# Copy MyISAM tables from Solaris to Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, solaris, ext3, zfs

We are planning to move our production databases from Solaris to Red Hat Linux. Our databases are purely MyISAM.

If we just copy files from zfs (solaris) filesystem to ext3 (linux) filesystem and start MySQL, will they be usable?

If they are not compatible, are there any ways to make them compatible on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

As long as both servers are the same architecture you should be all right, otherwise you will need to use mysqldump.

See: [Copying MySQL Databases to Another Machine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/copying-databases.html)

Comment: Server architecture would be same for both the servers. Only the OS will differ (Old OS: Solaris, New OS: Red Hat Linux). I just want to know is **'Will file copy from Solaris to Linux cause my database failure while accessing MyISAM tables?'**

Comment: @AbhijitBuchake As mentioned in the documentation I linked to it should work. The link also suggests other ways to copy databases.